# Using findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths in one directory (divide into sub folders) using Python?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.3

I try to use 'findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths' function on MXD files using ArcView 10.3.1. The MXD files located in one directory (which is divided into folders and sub folders). Also in the sub folders there are MXD files.

This is the directory content location:

[image]

and this is the sub folders location (there are more MXD files in the other folders):

[image]

---

I write in python 2.7:

```py
import arcpy,os,sys,fnmatch  
from arcpy import env 

rootPath = r"G:\desktop\Project"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    env.workspace = r"G:\desktop\Project"
    for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
        print mxdname
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"G:\desktop\Project\\" + mxdname)  
         mxd.findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths(r"D:\PROJECTS\green_line\gis\layers", r"G:\PROJECTS\green_line\gis\layers")
        print 'findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths'
        mxd.save()
del mxd
```

The result is:

```
>>> 
landuse__3___20013.mxd
findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths
landuse__4___20013.mxd
findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths
landuse__3___20013.mxd
findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths
landuse__4___20013.mxd
findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths
landuse__3___20013.mxd
findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths
landuse__4___20013.mxd
findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths
landuse__3___20013.mxd
findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths
landuse__4___20013.mxd
findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths
landuse__3___20013.mxd
findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths
landuse__4___20013.mxd
findAndReplaceWorkspacePathslanduse__3___20013.mxd
findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths
landuse__4___20013.mxd
findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths
landuse__3___20013.mxd
findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths
landuse__4___20013.mxd
findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths
landuse__3___20013.mxd
findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths
landuse__4___20013.mxd
findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths
landuse__3___20013.mxd
findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths
landuse__4___20013.mxd
findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths
>>>
```

Now, there are two problems:

1. Why the code work only with the MXD files in the directory and not in the sub folders?
2. Why the code printed so many lines?

Answer (score 2):

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    env.workspace = r"G:\desktop\Project"
```

It's looping through the sub folders, but you keep setting your environment back to the root directory. Try:

```
import arcpy,os,sys,fnmatch  
from arcpy import env 

rootPath = r"G:\desktop\Project"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    env.workspace = root
    for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
        print root + '/' + mxdname
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdname)  
        mxd.findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths(r"D:\PROJECTS\green_line\gis\layers", r"G:\PROJECTS\green_line\gis\layers")
        print 'findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths'
        mxd.save()
```

And even though it's in almost every ESRI example, you don't need that final `del mxd` command.

Comment: i get an error  :>>>
landuse__4___20013.mxd
findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths
landuse__5___20013.mxd
findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths
landuse__1___20013.mxd

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:\Users\yaron\Desktop\findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths test.py", line 9, in <module>
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"G:\desktop\Project\\" + mxdname)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 611, in __init__
    assert (os.path.isfile(mxd) or (mxd.lower() == "current")), gp.getIDMessage(89004, "Invalid MXD filename")
AssertionError: Invalid MXD filename.

Comment: the code  don't loop in the MXD files in "20000" folder, just in the major directory

Comment: I edited my answer with a fix to one other bug in the `arcpy.mapping.MapDocument` call. Since you are setting your workspace in each loop, you don't need the full path in the mxdname.

Comment: i get an error:  >>> 
G:\desktop\Project/landuse__4___20013.mxd

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:\Users\yaron\Desktop\findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths test.py", line 9, in <module>
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdname)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 611, in __init__
    assert (os.path.isfile(mxd) or (mxd.lower() == "current")), gp.getIDMessage(89004, "Invalid MXD filename")
AssertionError: Invalid MXD filename.
>>>

Comment: when i just print mxdname after the for line and without the oter lines ,   it print all the mxd files just fine. i don't understand what's wrong in the code

Comment: >>> G:\desktop\Project/landuse__4___20013.mxd - somthing wrong with this sign /